# Is there a way to transform appsettings into env. variables in an asp.net core app?

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I've created a new asp.net core API and added the following settings into `appsettings.Development.json`:

```json
{
  "AZURE_TENANT_ID": "<tenant-id>",
  "AZURE_CLIENT_ID" : "<client-id>",
  "AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET": "<client-secret>"
}
```

**Note:** I haven't done anything other than added these settings and a "one liner" that tries to get one of them:

```csharp
var x = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AZURE_TENANT_ID");
```

But somehow, these settings are not added as environment variables. If I, for example create a new Azure Function, add the same settings into `local.settings.json` file and try to get one of them via `Environment.Get....` like above - everything works like intended.

I think (at least it feels like) that I've searched through all existing documentation by Microsoft in order to figure this out. I believe that there are some fundamental principals here that I don't understand and obviosly can't find.

Can someone please help me to understand the difference and why I'm get these settings as environment variables in an Azure Function but not in an asp.net core app?

**UPDATE:**
To clarify, I run this locally and not trying to get the variables in any production environment.

**Goal**
The application is calling another service in Azure which needs a JWT token. The goal here is to use [DefaultAzureCredential](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.identity.defaultazurecredential?view=azure-dotnet) and the credential type `EnvironmentCredential` to fetch a token regardless of whether the app is running locally or in Azure. When the app run in Azure it uses a user-assigned managed identity which will be assigned through the `AZURE_CLIENT_ID`, we don't need any other settings. But when the app is running locally, we can't refer to any managed identity so we need to specify `AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET` and `AZURE_TENANT_ID` as well.

Comment: `appsettings.Development.json` is only used when hosting environment is `Development`. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Comment: @DimitrisMaragkos I may have been unclear in my question, I run this locally for now and not in any other environment then Development. I've updated the question.

Comment: The app.settings.json file does not set environment variables. It's just a config file. There's other ways to set environment variables for an ASP.NET Core app. But why bother with environment variables? Why not use Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration to read the values from appsettings.json?

Comment: @mason thanks for your comment. The environment variables is intended to be read by [DefaultAzureCredential](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.identity.defaultazurecredential?view=azure-dotnet) and the credential type "EnvironmentCredential" so I only need the `AZURE_CLIENT_ID` variable when the app is running in Azure. I've updated my question with a "Goal" section

Comment: Fair enough. Another alternative would be to set those at a machine or user level instead of in a file.

Comment: @mason thanks for clarification anyway - "it's just a config file". Then I don't need to try to solve the "automatic transport app.settings -> environment variable" problem :). Maybe I need to figure out another way to solve the authentication flow then, if you have any suggestion, I would like to talk about it further.

Comment: I still can't fully understand where is your problem. If you just want those environment variables for local development isn't `local.settings.json` enough for you? This is the exactly the reason why this file exists.

Comment: @DimitrisMaragkos the problem occurs when running an asp.net API application locally. I need to set environment variables that can be read by `DefaultAzureCredentials`. And to mention what @mason said - "The app.settings.json file does not set environment variables.". In fact, my question might be answered because an asp.net core app seems to not add appsettings as environment variables automatically like an Azure Function does.

Answer (score 3):

In the documentation for [`local.settings.json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local?tabs=v4%2Cwindows%2Ccsharp%2Cportal%2Cbash#local-settings) it says:

> The function app settings values can also be read in your code as
> environment variables.

The same does not apply for `appsettings.json` files. They are not meant to be used to define environment varibles.

For development you can define your environment variables inside [launchsettings.json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-6.0#development-and-launchsettingsjson):

```json
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:59481",
      "sslPort": 44308
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "EnvironmentsSample": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "dotnetRunMessages": true,
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:7152;http://localhost:5105",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development",
        "AZURE_TENANT_ID": "<tenant-id>",
        "AZURE_CLIENT_ID" : "<client-id>",
        "AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET": "<client-secret>"
      }
    },
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development",
        "AZURE_TENANT_ID": "<tenant-id>",
        "AZURE_CLIENT_ID" : "<client-id>",
        "AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET": "<client-secret>"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this would solve the problem but it will add another problem - The values will be added to the versioning and I don't want to have secrets in any repo.

Comment: @Scrat you would have had the same problem with appsettings.json. So set the environment level at the machine or user level instead of putting them in a file.

Comment: @mason yes that's true, but I've added the settings to `appsettings.Development.json` which is included in gitignore. That might not be recommended (to ignore that file) but as it is per now, I can't really see why we need that file. If I need to include this file in the furure, I will probably introduce the "Secret Manager" or similar.